# Firestore React get document by URL

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-cloud-firestore

I have a question about the operation that can be used with firestore

I have a table displaying a list of documents. (***url**: localhost/dashboard/users*)

When I click on a document in the list, I want to be redirected to a details page. (***url**: localhost/dashboard/user/1*)

Except that with firestore, my url is represented in this form:
(***url**: localhost/dashboard/user/MuVsCLALiQPZuxnV3yyQ*)

How do you get a details page with a "clean" URL.

Knowing that I want to be able to display the details of a user by going through the complete url and without necessarily going through the list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by "clean" you mean integers or shorter UIDs then you'll can store a field in user's Firestore document e.g. `{shortUid: 1}` (or set that short UID as document ID at first place) and then query based on the ID:

```
const userId = getIdFromURL();

const user = await getDocs(collection(db, "users"), where("shortUid", "==", userId))
```

Using sequential IDs is not recommended with NoSQL databases like Firestore so do checkout [Firestore Best Practices](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/best-practices#hotspots)